# How change when Label is in the attributes type. The sample code is given below

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('lbltipAddedComment').innerText = 'Your tip has been submitted!';
</script>
<label for="lbltipAddedComment">Comment</label>
<input type="text" id="lbltipAddedComment" value="ABC"/>
```

This is not working in my case!

Answer (score 0):

1. `.getElementById()` gets an element by **ID**.
2. `lbltipAddedComment` of the `label` tag is **NOT** a value of **ID** but a value of the **for** attribute. Your code gets the `input` tag by mistake.
3. To get an element by **for**, use `.querySelector()` instead. Or add ID to the `label` tag.

```js
document.querySelector('[for="lbltipAddedComment"]').innerText = 'Your tip has been submitted!';
```

```html
<label id="foo" for="lbltipAddedComment">Comment</label>
<input type="text" id="lbltipAddedComment" value="ABC"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a span tag after the input:

```js
document.getElementById('msg').innerText = 'Your tip has been submitted!';
```

```css
#msg{color:red}
```

```html
<label for="lbltipAddedComment">Comment</label>
<input type="text" id="lbltipAddedComment" value="ABC" />
<span id="msg"></span>
```